# When designing for tablet, is it better to restrict the app to one layout?

Tags: mobile-application, tablet, device-rotation

With more features being added to our app, it becomes more challenging to design for both landscape AND portrait, while trying to maintain optimal layouts for both cases. Often than we expect the layout needs to be slightly different when you rotate between portrait and landscape.

I've come across apps that only stick to one layout, either portrait or landscape.

what's really the benefit of designing for 2 layouts? most users won't rotate their tablet screens so often and it might be even annoying the layout accidently change when using the app while traveling for instance.

Comment: We can't live in the past!  Of course *everything should be reactive*.  Yes, certainly it should work both ways.  (Sure, if it's literally certain types of game, it's totally normal that Mario only works in landscape. Putting aside that ridiculous exception - *everything is reactive now*)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the type of app.

If its a game then one layout will do.

In case of data intensive site then both layouts would be required.

The normal user expectation is to change to landscape if the content seems too cramped in portrait view. Otherwise they usually continue with portrait view.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an released app? If it is and you've already introduced the notion of landscape or portrait usage it might be problematic to remove it is an option (possible user backlash).

If not then it's okay to prescribe an orientation, just as long as you are consistent. The main benefits are reduction in design and developed costs.

If this in some kind of MVP then all the more reason to stick with one orientation whilst you test your assumptions - no point designing a multi-layout responsive design if the app doesn't take off.

It's quite difficult to answer your question comprehensively without understand the type of app it is, the size of your organisation, the amount of active users and the stage of release etc.